# Python unicode: how to replace character that cannot be decoded using utf8 with whitespace?

Tags: python, unicode, utf-8

How to replace characters that cannot be decoded using utf8 with whitespace?

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
print unicode('\x97', errors='ignore') # print out nothing
print unicode('ABC\x97abc', errors='ignore') # print out ABCabc
```

How can I print out `ABC abc` instead of `ABCabc`? Note, `\x97` is just an example character. The characters that cannot be decoded are unknown inputs.

- If we use `errors='ignore'`, it will print out nothing.
- If we use `errors='replace'`, it will replace that character with some special chars.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use a `try-except` statement to handle the `UnicodeDecodeError` :

```
def my_encoder(my_string):
   for i in my_string:
      try :
         yield unicode(i)
      except UnicodeDecodeError:
         yield '\t' #or another whietespaces
```

And then use `str.join` method to join your string :

```
print ''.join(my_encoder(my_string))
```

Demo :

```
>>> print ''.join(my_encoder('this is a\x97n exam\x97ple'))
this is a   n exam  ple
```

Comment: \x97 is just an example character. The characters that cannot be decoded are unknown inputs.

Comment: @DehengYe Just a typo, fixed

Comment: very helpful answer! @Kasramvd

Comment: I hope you don't mind. Both you and @HelloWorld provide excellent answers. But Stack Overflow allows only one solution.

Answer (score 9):

Take a look at `codecs.register_error`. You can use it to register custom error handlers

https://docs.python.org/2/library/codecs.html#codecs.register_error

```
import codecs
codecs.register_error('replace_with_space', lambda e: (u' ',e.start + 1))
print unicode('ABC\x97abc', encoding='utf-8', errors='replace_with_space')
```

Comment: Does stack overflow allow more than 1 solution? both @Kasramvd and you provide excellent answers... what to do in this case..